# TSQL: XOR of varbinaries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xor, varbinary

Is there a way to get a `varbinary` that is the result of XORing two other `Varbinaries`?

This is for SQL Server 2012+

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is the XOR-Operator in T-SQL:

```
 SELECT 32 ^ 16;
```

This performs a bitwise XOR with the bitmaps of these two numbers.

But - according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - at least one side of the operator must be `int`, `smallint` or `tinyint`.

So, no, there is no *built-in* support for `VARBINARY XOR VARBINARY`.

You might think about a CLR function...